# Angular event emitter on multiple items

Tags: angular, events, output, observable, dom-events

I am developing an application but I have a small problem. I have a list of books that load using an ngfor with 3 components (header, content, footer). In my header I have a "like" button allowing me to follow the author.

When I click on it I can send the action to my parent component but I would like to know how to propagate the action on all the other books of the same author without reloading the page.

Can you help me please?

[image]

thanks

Comment: You'll need to post the code that you've tried so far.

Comment: I tried with invent emitter output and with view children but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow a simple message pattern, with a service for example:

```
export interface Message {
  message: string,
  receiver: string
}
```

```
this.messagesService.sendMessage(
  { message: 'likeButton', receiver: 'all' }
);
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Message } from '@shared/interfaces/message.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessagesService {
  constructor() { }

  private subject = new Subject<any>();

  sendMessage(message: Message) {
    this.subject.next(message);
  }

  subscribeToMessagesChannel(): Observable<Message> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

And in any place where you want:

```
this.messagesServiceSubscription = this.messagesService.subscribeToMessagesChannel().subscribe(
      message => {
        if (message.receiver === 'likeButton') {
          // Search in your structure and change the value to turn on the button.
        }
      }
    );
```

Dont forget unsuscribe:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.messagesServiceSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

You can update the message to send the id of the author, for example.

Maybe it is a more complex solution than other but you can set it on your project and use it in a lot of scenarios, doing your components communication more easy than the normal parent-child.

Comment: Thanks ! I tried your solution but my Childs components don't received the new value. I added a TrackByFn in my ngfor and same problem :(